# python tkiner- Name frame is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I have find many questions like mine in site. But these answers can't help me, so I had to put a question again.

```
from tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(slef):
        self.helloLabel = Label(self, text = 'Hello, world!')
        self.helloLabel.pack()
        self.quitButton = Button(self, text='Quit', command = self.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack()
app = Application()
app.master.title('Hello World')
app.mainloop()
```

my os is windows10 and python version is 3.4.3

Comment: Do you mean `Frame is not defined`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the contents of the error`name 'Frame' is not defined`

Comment: @SDilmac I had changed it but no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue really is -

```
NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined
```

Then my guess is that you have a tkinter.py in your system that is masking the actual `tkinter` module from library. If this is the case, then rename that file, such that it does not mask the library module.

---

Also, for the code posted above you have another issue, which would be the following from `self.createWidgets()` method -

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

This is because you have misspelled `self` in your `createWidgets` method. It should be `self` not `slef` , but you are trying to use `self` itself there. Example -

```
def createWidgets(self):
```

Comment: Are you sure the `from tkinter import *` line is really there?

Comment: Do you have a `tkinter.py` in your working directory? Is your file called `tkinter.py` ?

Comment: Instead of editing your unrelated wrong answer with guesses, it should be deleted and any question relating to the question should be added to the comments

Comment: Think you ! I knew what wrong with my code, I had a tkinter.py in my working directory

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No idea what you are talking about.

Comment: oh i see sorry friend , delete comments... accept my apologize !

Comment: Its ok, no need to apologize :)